# Calculate Nulls with a date

Tags: sql, null

I have two dates: a `StartDate` and a `CreatedDate`

If I say

```
CreatedDate < StartDate
```

what will happen if `StartDate` is `NULL`?

Should I use

```
isnull(startdate,0)
```

or will it just return a `NULL` or will it always be less than `StartDate` as `StartDate` is `NULL`?

Comment: As far as what would happen, what happened when you tried it?  As far as what you should do, what are your business rules?

Comment: More to the point, what _should_ happen when `StartDate` is `NULL`? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any ordinary comparisons (>, <, >=, <=, =, <>, like, in) return null if at least one of their arguments is null; so CreatedDate < StartDate returns null if StartDate is null. You can test for null explicitly:

```
  ((CreatedDate < StartDate) or (StartDate is null))
```

Or you can transform the StartDate value

```
  (CreatedDate < NVL(StartDate, To_Date('1.1.1000', 'DD.MM.YYYY')) -- <- Oracle Syntax
```

Comment: THANK YOU THAT IS THE PERFECT ANSWER I WAS LOOKING FOR COMPREHENSIVE AND TO THE POINT

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for `null`.

If you don't check for `null` then your compare will result in `unknown` which is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

If both `StartDate` and `CreatedDate` can be `NULL`, you can use the SQL [`COALESCE` function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) to provide default values, for example a small enough date and a big enough one:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE COALESCE(StartDate, DATE '0001-01-01') < COALESCE(CreatedDate, DATE '9999-12-31')
```

Here I am using [standard SQL date and time literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

*Note*: date and time limits vary on different database servers. The above example [works for the Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00200)